# Get maximum of array values by iterating all objects of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON where I need to get the single maximum value of the maximum number. The below code displays maximum of each item, but I need to get the Max out of all the items. Here the expected answer is 78

```
for(var x in items) {
  console.log("Max is" + Math.Max(items[x]));
}


var items = {
    "title": "Find Max",
    "A": [0, 78],
    "Z": [1],
    "R": [2, 10],
    "N": [2, 10, 56],
    "P": [5, 56]
}
```

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: 78 is the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of each property of your object; filter those values to only return the arrays (using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)), and then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to find the maximum value over all the arrays:

```js
var items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}
const max = Object.values(items).filter(v => Array.isArray(v)).reduce((c, v) => Math.max(c, ...v), Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(max);
```

This can be written without the `filter` by incorporating the logic into the `reduce`:

```js
var items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}
const max = Object.values(items).reduce((c, v) => Array.isArray(v) ? Math.max(c, ...v) : c, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(max);
```

If you can't use ES6 arrow functions, this will work:

```js
var items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}
const max = Object.values(items).filter(function(v) {
  return Array.isArray(v);
}).reduce(function(c, v) {
  return Math.max(c, ...v);
}, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(max);
```

If the spread operator is also unavailable, you can use `Array.reduce` again to get the maximum value from the array:

```js
var items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}
const max = Object.values(items).filter(function(v) {
  return Array.isArray(v);
}).reduce(function(c, v) {
  return v.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }, c);
}, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: => is not allowed, could you help me without => operator?

Comment: @CodeGuy I've edited my answer with a solution which doesn't use arrow functions

Comment: @Nick if arrow functions aren't valid, then spread syntax probably isn't either. You'll need `Function.prototype.apply()`

Comment: @Phil have edited in a solution which doesn't use spread either. But it seems that wasn't the problem with arrow functions.

Comment: strange algorithm, why `filter` followed by `reduce` when `reduce` is more generic? why `Math.max(c, Math.max(...v))` which is the same as `Math.max(c, ...v)`?

Comment: @Thankyou good call on the `Math.max`, that was a bit silly. I put the `filter` in to make it obvious what was going on, I agree that it would be more efficient to incorporate it into the `reduce` and I've made a note about that.

Comment: `Math.max(c, v.reduce(function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b) }))` is the worse version of `v.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a,b) }, c)`. the latter will not fail when `v` is an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll enjoy the simplicity and efficiency of this algorithm -

```js
const items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}

const nums =
  Object.values(items).flatMap(function (x) {
    if (Array.isArray(x))
      return x
    else
      return []
  })
  
const result =
  Math.max(-Infinity, ...nums)

console.log(result)
// 78
```

If `items` does not contain any numbers, the result will be `-Infinity`

---

**generators**

Here's another interesting approach using generators, if they are allowed. I think generators are particularly useful in this situation because `input` is a complex object. `items` is nested and some of the values we need to compare are non-numeric. It'd be nice we had a `values` function that could produce a stream of *all* nested values -

```js
const values = function* (t)
{ if (Array.isArray(t))
    for (const v of t)
      yield* values(v)
  else if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield* values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

const items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}

let r = -Infinity
for (const v of values(items))
  if (Number(v) === v)
    r = Math.max(r, v)
console.log(r)
// 78
```

Generators return an iterator. An iterator gives us one value and will not compute the next one until we ask for it. Generators are called "lazy" because of this. Note we can use `for..of` to iterate through a generator, exactly as we do with arrays.

But if you use this technique, don't stop here. Even though generators do not return arrays, we can write code that allows us to conceptualise the two similarly.

We could write general functions like `filter` to select values matching a predicate, eg `isNumber` -

```js
const isNumber = function(x)
{ return Number(x) === x
}

const filter = function* (test, t)
{ for (const v of t)
    if (test(v))
      yield v
}

for (const v of filter(isNumber, values(items)))
  console.log(v)

0
78
1
2
10
2
10
56
5
56
```

And we could write `reduce` -

```
const reduce = function(f, init, t)
{ let r = init
  for (const v of t)
    r = f(r, v)
  return r
}

const result =
  reduce
    ( Math.max
    , -Infinity
    , filter(isNumber, values(items))
    )

console.log(result)
// 78
```

Run the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const values = function* (t)
{ if (Array.isArray(t))
    for (const v of t)
      yield* values(v)
  else if (Object(t) === t)
    for (const v of Object.values(t))
      yield* values(v)
  else
    yield t
}

const filter = function* (test, t)
{ for (const v of t)
    if (test(v))
      yield v
}
 
const reduce = function(f, init, t)
{ let r = init
  for (const v of t)
    r = f(r, v)
  return r
}

const isNumber = function(x)
{ return Number(x) === x
}

const items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}
  
const result =
  reduce
    ( Math.max
    , -Infinity
    , filter(isNumber, values(items))
    )

console.log(result)
// 78
```

Answer (score 1):

A little less complex code for newbies:

```
var items = {
  "title": "Find Max",
  "A": [0, 78],
  "Z": [1],
  "R": [2, 10],
  "N": [2, 10, 56],
  "P": [5, 56]
}

let array = [];

for (const property in items) {
  if (Array.isArray(items[property])) {
    let newArray = items[property];
    array = [...array, ...newArray]
  }
}

console.log(Math.max(...array)) // 78
```